# Firestore get docs based off value existing in array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a little bit of a mental block in terms of how to do some relational queries with firestore while adhering to the best practices. I am creating a feed feature where you can see a feed of posts from your friends. Essentially my data structure is as follows:

```
Friends (collection)
-friend_doc
  ...data
  friends_uid: [uid1, uid2]

Posts (collection)
-post_doc
  ...data
  posted_by: uid2
```

Basically I am making a query to get all of the friends where the *friends_uid* contains my uid (uid1 in this case). And then once I mapped all of the friends uid's to an array, I want to make a firestore query to get posts where the *posted_by* field is equal to any of the uid's in that array of friends uid's. I haven't been able to make something that does anything like that yet.

I know that it seems most convenient to loop through the string array of friends uid's and make a query for each one like:

```
  listOfUids.forEach(async (item) => {
    const postQuerySnapshot = await firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .where('uid', '==', item)
      .get();
    results.push(postQuerySnapshot.docs);
  });
```

but this is extremely problematic for paging and limiting data as I could possibly receive tons of posts.  I may just be too deep into this code and missing an obvious solution or maybe my data structure is somewhat flawed. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**TLDR** - how can I make a firestore query that gets all docs that have a value that exists in an array of strings?

Comment: I realize this question is somewhat broad as it takes into consideration structuring data in firestore, I just haven't been able to find a good example of creating a feed feature in firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ["in" query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) for this:

```
firestore()
    .collection('posts')
    .where('uid', 'in', [uid1, uid2, ...])
```

But you are limited to 10 elements in that array.  So you are probably going to have to stick to what you have now.  You will not be able to use Firestore's pagination API.

Your only real alternatives for this case is to create a new collection that contains all of the data you want to query in one place, as there are no real join operations.  Duplicating data like this is common for nosql type databases.

Comment: Yes that in query is exactly what I'm looking for but I saw the 10 elements limit as well. Is there really no better way to structure a social media type feed feature in firestore than duplicating all that data into one place? Sounds like it'll cost a lot in terms of reads and writes and be overkill in the codebase.

Comment: There is no better way.  Data duplication is normal for massively scalable databases like Firestore.  If you don't need massive scalability, then perhaps another database would work better.